# CR | Copy data to another row using a formula field or variable

Tags: variables, crystal-reports, reporting

Here is my problem:

[Raw data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPZ9Y.png)

If there is a position 105 and 150, I need the material number of position 150. If there is only position 105, I need the material number of position 105.

On the right side of the picture you can see the correct selected material number.
Now I need to assign this data to position 100 (bc I will use a counter later on, which is depending on position 100).

---

Here you can see more of the raw data of the report (I can´t insert the complete report here, I use the details area only for testing).
I marked one "group"  in which you can see why I can´t change the order of the positions. In this case I need to use position 105 to output the material number (number rightmost on the red border) because there is no position 150.

[Raw data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KtDi.png)

Here is another example with position 150 used for the material number (the correct material number will be placed on position 105 every time):

[Raw data 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAFFm.png)

To use this material number in my following tables, it need to be assigned to position 100.

Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe there is a "copy"-function in crystal?
I use the whileprintingrecords method to read all the data and then copy the 105 value to the 100 position - is that possible with a copy function?

Comment: Formulas using the "WhilePrintingRecords" directive are evaluated when the section is rendered, that contains the formula. Therefore, to use anything from another record (or group header, or whatever...), this "anything" must be rendered in a section before. In your example you could inverse the order of records, then collect something from position 150, then use this is position 105. Aggregates placed in group or report headers can also be collected. 

But maybe you should describe the problem as a whole to enlarge the space of possible solutions.

Comment: May you show the final desired output? May you show a screenshot of your designer? 0100, 0105, 0150 are the only possible values?

Comment: Position 100, 105 and 150 need to be in this exact order, because I check if the 150 follows the 105 etc.
Therefore I can´t change the order.

Comment: I added some information in the question.

Comment: Is there no blunt method to copy the content from my formula field (which grabs the correct material number) to the empty space for position 100? Maybe with another formula field or something?